# Custom domain not pointing to Heroku project

Tags: html, node.js, heroku, dns, cname

I have deployed my node js project on Heroku but I am not able to point my domain (purchased from ionos.ca) to the Heroku dns target. I have made two domains in heroku dashboard:

> *.mysite.com, DNS Target: aqueous-jay-p8wmra8eyzlv3gzckdhj99je.herokudns.com
>
> [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), DNS Target:
> experimental-turnip-ha25x6iwdwmb4xzxtsdrhj3k.herokudns.com

Then in my ionos.ca domain portal, I changed the CNAME to

> aqueous-jay-p8wmra8eyzlv3gzckdhj99je.herokudns.com

But whenever I visit [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) I get an error saying

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) sent an
> invalid response.

Visiting mysite.com gives me this error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> mysite.com’s server IP address could not be found.

Any idea how I could fix this? I have been trying to make it work since last 1 hour :(

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your SSL/TLS setup. Fiddler4/Wireshark is showing `Internal Error (80)` I found some references that may help here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436412/openssl-connection-alert-internal-error` If you are using NGINX then post your config I can help with that.

```
Frame 138: 61 bytes on wire (488 bits), 61 bytes captured (488 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Fortinet_d4:fd:97 (70:4c:a5:d4:fd:97), Dst: Dell_b3:a3:f6 (b8:85:84:b3:a3:f6)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 52.73.16.193, Dst: 192.168.1.40
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 63037, Seq: 1, Ack: 221, Len: 7
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Internal Error)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Internal Error (80)
```